# Sending email using javax?

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail

I want to send email using javax.mail. When I run the following code it give me this error No provider for hwangheera4hagarmaher. Where is the problem, and how can I fix this error ?

the code  i used is this:

```
public static boolean SendMail (String subject, String from, String Password, String Message, String to[])
{
    String Host = "hwangheera4hagarmaher@gmail.com";

    Properties Property = System.getProperties();
    Property.put("mail.hwangheera4hagarmaher.starttls.enable", true);
    Property.put ("mail.hwangheera4hagarmaher.host", Host);
    Property.put ("mail.hwangheera4hagarmaher.user", from);
    Property.put ("mail.hwangheera4hagarmaher.password", Password);
    Property.put ("mail.hwangheera4hagarmaher.port", 587);
    Property.put ("mail.hwangheera4hagarmaher.auth", "true");

    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(Property, null);

    MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage (session);

    try
    {
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress (from));

        InternetAddress [] toAddress = new InternetAddress[to.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < to.length; i++)
        {
            toAddress [i] = new InternetAddress (to[i]);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < toAddress.length; i++)
        {
            message.addRecipient(RecipientType.TO, toAddress[i]);
        }

        message.setSubject (subject);
        message.setText(Message);

        Transport transport = session.getTransport("hwangheera4hagarmaher");
        transport.connect (Host, from, Password);
        transport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
        transport.close();

        return true;
    }
    catch (MessagingException ex)
    {
        showMessageDialog (null, ex);
    }
return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `hwangheera4hagarmaher` with `smtp` in all props and `getTransport ()` *unless* you have coded a provider by that name yourself.

Your hostname should be a server, not an email address. Maybe `smtp.gmail.com`?

By default Google provides security precaution for using any external access, especially If you use some email frameworks to access your account , first you need to give access, sign in your account then go to :

https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha

Then follow the rest to allow access to your account.

Comment: this error is gone now, but gmail prevented the code from sending the mail :/